# How to update only one record of duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update status to inactive ( Status=’I’) for all duplicate record except one in sql, default status is active (Status=’A’ ) for all records in table. It should be done without using any inbuilt sql function ex: row_num(), rank(), set rowcount etc.

```
CREATE TABLE dup_test
(
   Emp_ID INT,
   Mgr_ID INT,
   Status Varchar(5)
 )

INSERT INTO dup_test VALUES (1,1,'A');
INSERT INTO dup_test VALUES (1,1,'A');
INSERT INTO dup_test VALUES (1,1,'A');
INSERT INTO dup_test VALUES (2,2,'A');
INSERT INTO dup_test VALUES (2,2,'A');
INSERT INTO dup_test VALUES (3,3,'A');
```

Expected Result:

Emp_ID, Mgr_ID, Status

```
1        1        A
1        1        I
1        1        I
2        2        A
2        2        I
3        3        A
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And why don't you want to use built-in functions?

Comment: This question was asked in one of the interview and they wanted to achieve it without using build-in function, I am using SQL 2008 server.

Can we achieve it using while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the table and add an identity column (ID):

`ALTER TABLE dup_test
ADD id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)`

Then something like the following will work:

`UPDATE dup_test SET
   Status='I'
FROM dup_test dt LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (SELECT Emp_ID, MAX(ID) AS maxid
    FROM dup_test
    GROUP BY Emp_ID) AS dt2 ON dt.Emp_ID=dt2.Emp_ID AND dt.ID=dt2.maxid
WHERE dt2.maxID IS NULL`

Comment: I cannot alter table as it is in production, even will not be able to use any temp table to use "IDENTITY (1, 1)" due to large amount of data.

Comment: The only other trick I can think of is to set all the rows to I, then use a cursor to loop through each Emp_ID/Mgr_ID combo and set the TOP 1 to 'A'